# Regex to extract substrings in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, c#-4.0

I have a string as:

```
 string subjectString = @"(((43*('\\uth\Hgh.Green.two.190ITY.PCV')*9.8)/100000+('VBNJK.PVI.10JK.PCV'))*('ASFGED.Height Density.1JKHB01.PCV')/476)";
```

My expected output is:

```
Hgh.Green.two.190ITY.PCV
VBNJK.PVI.10JK.PCV
ASFGED.Height Density.1JKHB01.PCV
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
 Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"'[^\\]*.PCV");
 Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
 string val = matchResults.Value;
```

This works when the input string is :`"@"(((43*('\\uth\Hgh.Green.two.190ITY.PCV')*9.8)/100000+";` but when the string grows and the number of substrings to be extracted is more than 1 , I am getting undesired results .

How do I extract three substrings from the original string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to match word and `.` chars before `.PCV`.

Use

```
[\w\s.]*\.PCV
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5cw%5cs.%5d*%5c.PCV&i=%28%28%2843*%28%27%5c%5cuth%5cHgh.Green.two.190ITY.PCV%27%29*9.8%29%2f100000%2b%28%27VBNJK.PVI.10JK.PCV%27%29%29*%28%27ASFGED.Height+Density.1JKHB01.PCV%27%29%2f476%29)

To force at least 1 word char at the start use

```
\w[\w\s.]*\.PCV
```

Optionally, if needed, add a word boundary at the start: `@"\b\w[\w\s.]*\.PCV"`.

To force `\w` match only ASCII letters and digits (and `_`) compile the regex object with `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option.

Here,

- `\w` - matches any letter, digit or `_`
- `[\w\s.]*` - matches 0+ whitespace, word or/and `.` chars
- `\.` - a literal `.`
- `PCV` - a `PCV` substring.

Sample usage:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(str, @"\w[\w\s.]*\.PCV")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m=>m.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I think you need to escape the '.' also, like this: `[\w\.]*\.PCV`

Comment: @BG100: No, inside a character class only `-`, `]`, ``\``, `^` need escaping. And `]` needs no escaping if it is the first char, and `^` needs no escaping if it is not the first char, and `-` does not need escaping if it is the first/last char in the character class.

Comment: Ah! I didn't realise that! Just tried it and you're right... :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : The results[2] is :"Density.1JKHB01.PCV" but I need "ASFGED.Height Density.1JKHB01.PCV" although the other two results are correct.

Comment: Add a whitespace to the class - `@"\w[\w\s.]*\.PCV"` then. Else, please precise the requirements. I still would follow the whitelisting approach here  unless you are sure about what the *delimiter* pattern should look like.